# Update with Special Characters

Tags: apache-nifi

Team,

Need your help

I am trying to import the data from Oracle to PostgreSQL I have columns and data below like this

Doc_id City_Name Cre_date Mod_Date

1      Dallas    06/Feb   07/Feb

2      Vegas     06/Feb   07/Feb

3      Florida   06/Feb   07/Feb

4      Texas     06/Feb   07/Feb

I have imported raw data and want to get the updated records frequently

My Flow is: QueryDatabaseTable-->UpdateAttribute-->RouteOnAttribute-->PutDatabaseRecord

For that, I'm using In QueryDatabaseTable maximum columns Mod_Date, But I am getting an error with special character If I gave without underscore I am getting but with underscore I am not getting data could you please suggest how will I use with special character

Would be a great help.

Comment: Can you supply the error you're getting when you use the underscore?

Comment: @mattb thanks for the reply, Error: Column "Docid" does not exist, but I have a column with Doc_id(source and target table). And one more case while inserting the data if i have a 2 columns, one with underscore(city_id) and one without underscore(cityid) in that case getting  Error:column "cityid"  specified more than once

Comment: Try adding separate success and failure connections from PutDatabaseRecord -> LogAttribute, so you can see if your flow files are successful or failing. Are you getting errors with PutDatabaseRecord (red square in the top right corner of the processor, also stack traces in `logs/nifi-app.log`), and do the flow files go to success or failure (after adding the connections as described above)?

Comment: yes, I'm getting the error with PutDatabseRecord and I can able to get the error in a log file as well, and I tried with LogAttribute separate connections success and failure but no luck. the data queued before PutDatabaseRecord (if you don't mind can you create and send me template then i can cross-check whether I'm in a proper flow or not) https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/238854/updates-with-special-characters.html

Comment: If you have a field city_id and cityid, make sure Translate Field Names is false in PutDatabaseRecord